# Is it better to have events within JavaScript objects or outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Is it better to have events within JavaScript objects or outside?

for example here is some simple code to produce a toolbar that pops up at the bottom of a page (I'm using jQuery here):

```
tool_bar = {    
  show : function() {
    $('#bottomBox')
      .show()
      .animate({ 'bottom'  : '0' }, 700)
    ;
  },
  close : function() {
    $('#bottomBox').hide();     
  }
};

$(function() {  
  $('#bottomBox span').click(function() {
    tool_bar.hide();
  });
});

window.onload = function() {
  tool_bar.show();
};
```

In the above I have the events outside the tool_bar object. Is this better or this:

```
tool_bar = {    
  show : function() {
    window.onload = function() {
      $('#bottomBox')
        .show()
        .animate({ 'bottom' : '0' }, 700)
      ;
    };
  },
  close : function() {
    $('#bottomBox span').click(function() {
      $('#bottomBox').hide();       
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  tool_bar.close();
});

tool_bar.show();
```

Should mention, both work. I just want to know what's considered better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that encapsulation is a worthy goal.  This means that you encapsulate the behaviors of an object within that object.  The outside world should have control over installing or removing the object and be able to control any other behaviors that the client might want to, but behaviors that are "within" the object should be implemented entirely within the object (at least for default behavior).

In your specific case, I think you should allow an outside agent to install the toolbar or remove the toolbar, but the operation of the toolbar once installed should be handled by the toolbar itself.

I'd suggest an implementation like this with these advantages:

- All behavior is encapsulated within the object
- Because the id is passed in to the constructor, you can have more than one
- The object takes care of managing it's own event handler, the outside world doesn't have to know about that.
- It has externally available methods for `show()` and `hide()`.
- You can easily add additional behaviors.

You'd implement a toolbar like this:

```
var bottomToolbar = new tool_bar("bottomBox", true);
```

And, here's the code for the object:

```
// id is a required argument
// show is an optional argument (true means to show it as soon as possible)
var tool_bar = function(id, show) {
    this.id = '#' + id;

    this.show = function() {
        $(this.id).show().animate({ 'bottom'  : '0' }, 700);
    };

    this.hide = function() {
        $(this.id).hide();
    };

    // .ready() code will either be fired immediately if document already ready
    // or later when document is ready, so the code can be used either way
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (show) {
            this.show();
        }
        $(this.id + " span").click(function() {
            this.hide();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
$(function() {  

  var bottom = $('#bottomBox')
    .show()
    .animate({
      'bottom': '0'
    }, 700);

  $('span', bottom).click(function() {
    bottom.hide();     
  });

});
```

You could also make it a plugin:

```
$.fn.toolbar = function(){

  this
    .show()
    .animate({
      'bottom': '0'
    }, 700);

  $('span', this).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();     
  });

  return this;

}

$(function() {  

  $('#bottomBox').toolbar();

}
```

Comment: It seems that the OP had a `show()` method for a good reason.  After it's hidden, it would be nice to be able to show it again.  Your implementation no longer has a `show()` method.

Comment: @jfriend00: Doesn't seem so. The second implementation in the question doesn't have such a show method.

Comment: OK, but the first implementation does.

Answer (score 0):

Ones you have something declared or built-in - it doesn't really matter, where do you redefine it's value;

In your case the result of the two codes will be identical.
The only difference is that when you declare: `var x = "x";` outside of a function or if, or any operator - it will become a global variable and it's value assigned immediately. 
You can also declare an empty var `var x;` as global var and assign a value by function or through any operator, which will stay there.
Since `window.onload` is an event of a global object - it doesn't matter, where do you assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

I favour a separation of mechanism and policy, so in your example I'd structure my code in the first way.

The second way isn't *bad* though, I'd just a) call the function something different like `showOnLoad()`, and b) use proper event registration (Guffa's answer has what's likely the best way of registering an "on load" event), not assignment to `window.onload`.